# ReactJS passing arrow function as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello there I am currently stuck on a problem where I don't know how to create a react component where I could later on pass something like this

```
<CustomComponent transform={e=> {...e, text = e.text.toUpperCase()}}> </CustomComponent>
```

Any tips/hints will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yu're trying to create an object in a concise arrow function, you have to wrap the object literal in `()` so the JavaScript parser knows you're not using a full function body. Also, you use `:`, not `=`, to separate property keys from their values in an object literal. So:

```
                                             v−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Colon, not equal sign
<CustomComponent transform={e => ({...e, text: e.text.toUpperCase()})}> </CustomComponent>
Parens −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Comment: Thank for the quick answer. The problem I am facing right now is that when I call the prop in the component and pass a parameter to it, it says that e.text is null.

Comment: ahh never mind I just overlooked that one of the objects was null. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const CustomComponent = ({ prop }) => {


     ...your code using prop (of any name you want)

}
export default CustomComponent
```

You should be able to import this later on as `<CustomComponent prop={myPropName} />`

If you had multiple it would look like:

```
 const CustomComponent = ({ p1, p2, p3 }) => {


     ...your code using prop (of any name you want)

}
export default CustomComponent
```

You should be able to import this later on as `<CustomComponent p1={myp1} p2={myp2}/>`

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass in a reference to a function that returns an object, but the syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
 transform={e => ({ ...e, text: e.text.toUpperCase() })}
```